# What Might Be Causing This Exception Access Violation?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-crash

I have a JAVA8 program that uses threading to iterate through a piece of code that uses a .dll behind the scenes, and every so often I get this access violation, but have no idea why.  As it doesn't happen every time, I am at a loss as to where to look in order to determine what is going wrong.  It creates no error if I run serially - but for performance purposes I would love to get this to reliably work in parallel.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000001800e9fee, pid=1324, tid=15040
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b15) (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jPortfolioPrecision-2.24.0.dll+0xe9fee]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000270f9800):  JavaThread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=15040, stack(0x000000002d690000,0x000000002d790000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffffffffffff

Registers:
RAX=0x0003ea0000050900, RBX=0x000000002c062870, RCX=0x000000000258dc18, RDX=0x000000002c062870
RSP=0x000000002d78ea68, RBP=0x000000003c9b44f0, RSI=0x000000000258dc18, RDI=0x00000000025880c0
R8 =0x000000004b68ffff, R9 =0x000000003c9b4500, R10=0x000000002d78ebe8, R11=0x000000003c9b44f0
R12=0x000000002d78eb50, R13=0x000000002d2f1db8, R14=0x000000002d78ecc8, R15=0x00000000270f9800
RIP=0x00000001800e9fee, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010297

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000002d78ea68)
0x000000002d78ea68:   0000000180025678 00000000277384f8
0x000000002d78ea78:   0000000000000000 0000000027738370
0x000000002d78ea88:   00000000270f9800 fffffffffffffffe
0x000000002d78ea98:   0000000027738370 00000000270f9800
0x000000002d78eaa8:   0000000100000000 00000000277384f8
0x000000002d78eab8:   0000000027738370 00000000270f9800
0x000000002d78eac8:   0000000100000000 0000000000000006
0x000000002d78ead8:   000000018036a908 0000000000000000
0x000000002d78eae8:   0000000000000000 00000000264ad370
0x000000002d78eaf8:   000000018036a908 0000000000000000
0x000000002d78eb08:   000000002d78eb80 000000003a5b9640
0x000000002d78eb18:   000000018002577d 000000000258dc18
0x000000002d78eb28:   000000002d78eca8 00000000328003b0
0x000000002d78eb38:   000000006fa48ef6 000000000258dc18
0x000000002d78eb48:   000000018015076b 0000000002848e60
0x000000002d78eb58:   0000000000000001 00000000328003b0 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000001800e9fee)
0x00000001800e9fce:   5c 24 20 e8 d6 9e 17 00 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc
0x00000001800e9fde:   cc cc 4c 8b 02 49 8b 40 10 48 89 02 49 8b 40 10
0x00000001800e9fee:   80 78 21 00 75 04 48 89 50 08 48 8b 42 08 49 89
0x00000001800e9ffe:   40 08 48 8b 41 08 48 3b 50 08 75 0d 4c 89 40 08 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0003ea0000050900 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000002c062870 is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000000258dc18 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000002c062870 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000002d78ea68 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000270f9800
RBP=0x000000003c9b44f0 is an unknown value
RSI=0x000000000258dc18 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000000025880c0 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000004b68ffff is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000003c9b4500 is an unknown value
R10=0x000000002d78ebe8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000270f9800
R11=0x000000003c9b44f0 is an unknown value
R12=0x000000002d78eb50 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000270f9800
R13={method} {0x000000002d2f1dc0} 'release' '()V' in 'com/axiomainc/portfolioprecision2/Portfolio'
R14=0x000000002d78ecc8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000270f9800
R15=0x00000000270f9800 is a thread


Stack: [0x000000002d690000,0x000000002d790000],  sp=0x000000002d78ea68,  free space=1018k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [jPortfolioPrecision-2.24.0.dll+0xe9fee]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.axiomainc.portfolioprecision2.Portfolio.release()V+0
j  com.axiomainc.portfolioprecision.optimization.RebalancingSolution$RebRunInfo.destroy()V+107
J 3775 C1 com.axiomainc.portfolioprecision.optimization.RebalancingSolution.resetRebRunInfo()V (20 bytes) @ 0x00000000032c0d5c [0x00000000032c0c80+0xdc]
j  com.axiomainc.portfolioprecision.optimization.RebalancingSolution.reset()V+65
J 4098 C1 Auction$$Lambda$1.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V (8 bytes) @ 0x0000000003d88ddc [0x0000000003d88b00+0x2dc]
J 4097 C1 java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V (11 bytes) @ 0x0000000002f5cc5c [0x0000000002f5cb40+0x11c]
j  java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)V+99
j  java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Ljava/util/stream/Sink;Ljava/util/Spliterator;)V+32
j  java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute()V+103
j  java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec()Z+1
j  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec()I+10
j  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Ljava/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask;)V+21
j  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue;)V+35
j  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run()V+24
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000026512800 JavaThread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=13904, stack(0x0000000029080000,0x0000000029180000)]
=>0x00000000270f9800 JavaThread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=15040, stack(0x000000002d690000,0x000000002d790000)]
  0x0000000029b95000 JavaThread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-0" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=13304, stack(0x000000002d430000,0x000000002d530000)]
  0x000000002497d000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6304, stack(0x0000000025ac0000,0x0000000025bc0000)]
  0x0000000024979000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1536, stack(0x00000000258d0000,0x00000000259d0000)]
  0x0000000024912800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9508, stack(0x0000000025790000,0x0000000025890000)]
  0x000000002491a800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12292, stack(0x0000000025520000,0x0000000025620000)]
  0x0000000024903800 JavaThread "JDWP Command Reader" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11188, stack(0x0000000025330000,0x0000000025430000)]
  0x0000000024902000 JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11868, stack(0x0000000025230000,0x0000000025330000)]
  0x00000000248f3000 JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8752, stack(0x0000000024d20000,0x0000000024e20000)]
  0x00000000233c9800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4572, stack(0x0000000025030000,0x0000000025130000)]
  0x00000000233c8800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13632, stack(0x0000000024ea0000,0x0000000024fa0000)]
  0x0000000023366800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13760, stack(0x00000000247f0000,0x00000000248f0000)]
  0x0000000023365800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13676, stack(0x0000000024690000,0x0000000024790000)]
  0x00000000027f8800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=11228, stack(0x0000000002c60000,0x0000000002d60000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000023360000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000024470000,0x0000000024570000] [id=14196]
  0x000000002497e800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000024580000,0x0000000024680000] [id=12964]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 2092032K, used 1807248K [0x000000072b200000, 0x00000007be880000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1939968K, 85% used [0x000000072b200000,0x00000007902a2b78,0x00000007a1880000)
  from space 152064K, 99% used [0x00000007b5400000,0x00000007be841650,0x00000007be880000)
  to   space 197120K, 0% used [0x00000007a6780000,0x00000007a6780000,0x00000007b2800000)
 ParOldGen       total 534528K, used 313588K [0x0000000601600000, 0x0000000622000000, 0x000000072b200000)
  object space 534528K, 58% used [0x0000000601600000,0x000000061483d3c0,0x0000000622000000)
 Metaspace       used 17911K, capacity 18122K, committed 18432K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1889K, capacity 1987K, committed 2048K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000012120000,0x0000000012f20000] byte_map_base: 0x000000000f115000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000070114040
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000013c80000, 0x000000001ac28000)
 End Bits:   [0x000000001ac28000, 0x0000000021bd0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000001d00000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=16432Kb max_used=17370Kb free=229327Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002d60000, 0x0000000003e80000, 0x0000000011d60000]
 total_blobs=3577 nmethods=3105 adapters=392
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 92.735 Thread 0x0000000024979000 nmethod 4179 0x0000000003a21a90 code [0x0000000003a21c00, 0x0000000003a21ed8]
Event: 92.735 Thread 0x0000000024979000 4180       3       com.axiomainc.portfolioprecision.WorkspaceDatedElement::destroy (10 bytes)
Event: 92.735 Thread 0x0000000024979000 nmethod 4180 0x000000000368f7d0 code [0x000000000368f940, 0x000000000368fae8]
Event: 92.735 Thread 0x0000000024979000 4181   !   3       java.io.PrintStream::write (69 bytes)
Event: 92.736 Thread 0x0000000024979000 nmethod 4181 0x0000000003a33490 code [0x0000000003a33660, 0x0000000003a33e18]
Event: 92.743 Thread 0x000000002491a800 4182       4       Auction::getDaysToComplete (129 bytes)
Event: 92.751 Thread 0x000000002491a800 nmethod 4182 0x0000000003ae2490 code [0x0000000003ae2740, 0x0000000003ae3320]
Event: 92.782 Thread 0x0000000024912800 4183       4       com.axiomainc.portfolioprecision.optimization.RebalancingBase::sanityCheck (1263 bytes)
Event: 92.782 Thread 0x000000002491a800 4184   !   4       com.axiomainc.portfolioprecision.optimization.Strategy::sanityCheck (252 bytes)
Event: 92.801 Thread 0x000000002491a800 nmethod 4184 0x00000000035648d0 code [0x0000000003564b80, 0x0000000003566548]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 40.446 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=9 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 959488K, used 959474K [0x000000072b200000, 0x0000000770b00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 876032K, 100% used [0x000000072b200000,0x0000000760980000,0x0000000760980000)
  from space 83456K, 99% used [0x0000000767a80000,0x000000076cbfcb80,0x000000076cc00000)
  to   space 115712K, 0% used [0x0000000760980000,0x0000000760980000,0x0000000767a80000)
 ParOldGen       total 306176K, used 138062K [0x0000000601600000, 0x0000000614100000, 0x000000072b200000)
  object space 306176K, 45% used [0x0000000601600000,0x0000000609cd3858,0x0000000614100000)
 Metaspace       used 14955K, capacity 15094K, committed 15232K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1596K, capacity 1661K, committed 1664K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 40.523 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=9 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 991744K, used 81636K [0x000000072b200000, 0x000000078fc00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 876032K, 0% used [0x000000072b200000,0x000000072b200000,0x0000000760980000)
  from space 115712K, 70% used [0x0000000760980000,0x00000007659393b8,0x0000000767a80000)
  to   space 123392K, 0% used [0x0000000788380000,0x0000000788380000,0x000000078fc00000)
 ParOldGen       total 306176K, used 142922K [0x0000000601600000, 0x0000000614100000, 0x000000072b200000)
  object space 306176K, 46% used [0x0000000601600000,0x000000060a192b90,0x0000000614100000)
 Metaspace       used 14955K, capacity 15094K, committed 15232K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1596K, capacity 1661K, committed 1664K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 46.380 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=10 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 991744K, used 957668K [0x000000072b200000, 0x000000078fc00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 876032K, 100% used [0x000000072b200000,0x0000000760980000,0x0000000760980000)
  from space 115712K, 70% used [0x0000000760980000,0x00000007659393b8,0x0000000767a80000)
  to   space 123392K, 0% used [0x0000000788380000,0x0000000788380000,0x000000078fc00000)
 ParOldGen       total 306176K, used 142922K [0x0000000601600000, 0x0000000614100000, 0x000000072b200000)
  object space 306176K, 46% used [0x0000000601600000,0x000000060a192b90,0x0000000614100000)
 Metaspace       used 17505K, capacity 17702K, committed 17920K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1873K, capacity 1955K, committed 2048K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 46.587 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=10 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1512960K, used 100949K [0x000000072b200000, 0x0000000791400000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1389568K, 0% used [0x000000072b200000,0x000000072b200000,0x000000077ff00000)
  from space 123392K, 81% used [0x0000000788380000,0x000000078e615780,0x000000078fc00000)
  to   space 135680K, 0% used [0x000000077ff00000,0x000000077ff00000,0x0000000788380000)
 ParOldGen       total 306176K, used 221581K [0x0000000601600000, 0x0000000614100000, 0x000000072b200000)
  object space 306176K, 72% used [0x0000000601600000,0x000000060ee636f0,0x0000000614100000)
 Metaspace       used 17505K, capacity 17702K, committed 17920K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1873K, capacity 1955K, committed 2048K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 62.091 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=11 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1512960K, used 1490517K [0x000000072b200000, 0x0000000791400000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1389568K, 100% used [0x000000072b200000,0x000000077ff00000,0x000000077ff00000)
  from space 123392K, 81% used [0x0000000788380000,0x000000078e615780,0x000000078fc00000)
  to   space 135680K, 0% used [0x000000077ff00000,0x000000077ff00000,0x0000000788380000)
 ParOldGen       total 306176K, used 221581K [0x0000000601600000, 0x0000000614100000, 0x000000072b200000)
  object space 306176K, 72% used [0x0000000601600000,0x000000060ee636f0,0x0000000614100000)
 Metaspace       used 17755K, capacity 17926K, committed 18176K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1886K, capacity 1987K, committed 2048K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 62.403 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=11 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1525248K, used 135657K [0x000000072b200000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1389568K, 0% used [0x000000072b200000,0x000000072b200000,0x000000077ff00000)
  from space 135680K, 99% used [0x000000077ff00000,0x000000078837a418,0x0000000788380000)
  to   space 176128K, 0% used [0x00000007b5400000,0x00000007b5400000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 306176K, used 269979K [0x0000000601600000, 0x0000000614100000, 0x000000072b200000)
  object space 306176K, 88% used [0x0000000601600000,0x0000000611da6ea0,0x0000000614100000)
 Metaspace       used 17755K, capacity 17926K, committed 18176K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1886K, capacity 1987K, committed 2048K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 62.403 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=12 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 1525248K, used 135657K [0x000000072b200000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1389568K, 0% used [0x000000072b200000,0x000000072b200000,0x000000077ff00000)
  from space 135680K, 99% used [0x000000077ff00000,0x000000078837a418,0x0000000788380000)
  to   space 176128K, 0% used [0x00000007b5400000,0x00000007b5400000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 306176K, used 269979K [0x0000000601600000, 0x0000000614100000, 0x000000072b200000)
  object space 306176K, 88% used [0x0000000601600000,0x0000000611da6ea0,0x0000000614100000)
 Metaspace       used 17755K, capacity 17926K, committed 18176K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1886K, capacity 1987K, committed 2048K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 63.545 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=12 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 1525248K, used 82137K [0x000000072b200000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1389568K, 0% used [0x000000072b200000,0x000000072b200000,0x000000077ff00000)
  from space 135680K, 60% used [0x000000077ff00000,0x0000000784f36770,0x0000000788380000)
  to   space 176128K, 0% used [0x00000007b5400000,0x00000007b5400000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 534528K, used 305719K [0x0000000601600000, 0x0000000622000000, 0x000000072b200000)
  object space 534528K, 57% used [0x0000000601600000,0x000000061408ddf0,0x0000000622000000)
 Metaspace       used 17755K, capacity 17926K, committed 18176K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1886K, capacity 1987K, committed 2048K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 77.576 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=13 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 1525248K, used 1471705K [0x000000072b200000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1389568K, 100% used [0x000000072b200000,0x000000077ff00000,0x000000077ff00000)
  from space 135680K, 60% used [0x000000077ff00000,0x0000000784f36770,0x0000000788380000)
  to   space 176128K, 0% used [0x00000007b5400000,0x00000007b5400000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 534528K, used 305719K [0x0000000601600000, 0x0000000622000000, 0x000000072b200000)
  object space 534528K, 57% used [0x0000000601600000,0x000000061408ddf0,0x0000000622000000)
 Metaspace       used 17860K, capacity 18054K, committed 18432K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1889K, capacity 1987K, committed 2048K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 77.894 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=13 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 2092032K, used 151813K [0x000000072b200000, 0x00000007be880000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1939968K, 0% used [0x000000072b200000,0x000000072b200000,0x00000007a1880000)
  from space 152064K, 99% used [0x00000007b5400000,0x00000007be841650,0x00000007be880000)
  to   space 197120K, 0% used [0x00000007a6780000,0x00000007a6780000,0x00000007b2800000)
 ParOldGen       total 534528K, used 313588K [0x0000000601600000, 0x0000000622000000, 0x000000072b200000)
  object space 534528K, 58% used [0x0000000601600000,0x000000061483d3c0,0x0000000622000000)
 Metaspace       used 17860K, capacity 18054K, committed 18432K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1889K, capacity 1987K, committed 2048K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 72.282 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000036fef6c method=java.text.DigitList.isZero()Z @ 7
Event: 72.283 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000036c6d7c method=java.text.DigitList.isZero()Z @ 7
Event: 76.727 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003dd7fe8 method=sun.misc.FloatingDecimal$BinaryToASCIIBuffer.dtoa(IJIZ)V @ 1245
Event: 76.794 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000038d093c method=Port.getTradedPercentages()Ljava/util/Map; @ 148
Event: 76.795 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000383dcb4 method=Port.getTradedPercentages()Ljava/util/Map; @ 148
Event: 76.949 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000038d093c method=Port.getTradedPercentages()Ljava/util/Map; @ 148
Event: 76.949 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000383dcb4 method=Port.getTradedPercentages()Ljava/util/Map; @ 148
Event: 77.026 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000387eb64 method=Auction.getDaysToComplete(Lcom/axiomainc/portfolioprecision/Asset;)Ljava/lang/Double; @ 4
Event: 92.533 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000038d093c method=Port.getTradedPercentages()Ljava/util/Map; @ 148
Event: 92.735 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003e40a08 method=Auctioneer.haveAllAssetsConverged(LAuction;)Z @ 236

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 26.360 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000032216b8 to 0x0000000003221f0d
Event: 26.360 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000002ed745e to 0x0000000002ed7831
Event: 26.361 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000032c0874 to 0x00000000032c0b5d
Event: 26.361 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000002f198ef to 0x0000000002f1995d
Event: 41.330 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000007359c3dc0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3627\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1125]
Event: 41.332 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000007359d23d0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3627\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1125]
Event: 41.374 Thread 0x000000002704a000 Implicit null exception at 0x000000000387822a to 0x000000000387879d
Event: 41.374 Thread 0x0000000026b57000 Implicit null exception at 0x000000000387822a to 0x000000000387879d
Event: 41.754 Thread 0x0000000026b57000 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000032c8144 to 0x00000000032c8899
Event: 46.692 Thread 0x0000000023365800 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000003237d94 to 0x000000000323862d

Events (10 events):
Event: 92.662 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000003a248c1 sp=0x0000000002d5f430
Event: 92.662 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000002da787f sp=0x0000000002d5f258 mode 0
Event: 92.678 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000003a248c1 sp=0x0000000002d5f430
Event: 92.678 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000002da787f sp=0x0000000002d5f258 mode 0
Event: 92.695 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000003a248c1 sp=0x0000000002d5f430
Event: 92.695 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000002da787f sp=0x0000000002d5f258 mode 0
Event: 92.735 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff65 fr.pc=0x0000000003e40a08
Event: 92.735 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000003e40a08 sp=0x0000000002d5f680
Event: 92.735 Thread 0x00000000027f8800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000002da582a sp=0x0000000002d5f6c8 mode 2
Event: 92.799 Thread 0x0000000026512800 Thread added: 0x0000000026512800


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013fcd0000 - 0x000000013fd07000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe
0x0000000077180000 - 0x0000000077329000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076f60000 - 0x000000007707f000     C:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd240000 - 0x000007fefd2ac000     C:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefe8b0000 - 0x000007fefe98b000     C:\windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefe700000 - 0x000007fefe79f000     C:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefe370000 - 0x000007fefe38f000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007feff2e0000 - 0x000007feff40d000     C:\windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000077080000 - 0x000000007717a000     C:\windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefe7a0000 - 0x000007fefe807000     C:\windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefe290000 - 0x000007fefe29e000     C:\windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefef90000 - 0x000007feff059000     C:\windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefb0c0000 - 0x000007fefb2b4000     C:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007feff410000 - 0x000007feff481000     C:\windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefe6d0000 - 0x000007fefe6fe000     C:\windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefe5c0000 - 0x000007fefe6c9000     C:\windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000007fefcec0000 - 0x000007fefcf2b000     C:\PROGRA~1\Citrix\System32\MFAPHOOK64.DLL
0x000007fefcde0000 - 0x000007fefce15000     C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICAService\picaFullScreenHookX64.dll
0x000007fefc590000 - 0x000007fefc5cc000     C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICAService\ShellHook64.dll
0x000007fefec20000 - 0x000007fefee23000     C:\windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefd500000 - 0x000007fefe288000     C:\windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fefcc40000 - 0x000007fefcdd3000     C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICAService\SCardHook64.dll
0x000007fefcc10000 - 0x000007fefcc36000     C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICAService\cxinjime64.dll
0x000007fee7770000 - 0x000007fee77e6000     C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICAService\PicaWtsHook64.dll
0x00000000795b0000 - 0x0000000079682000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000006f910000 - 0x0000000070193000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef19a0000 - 0x000007fef19a9000     C:\windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefe2a0000 - 0x000007fefe2ed000     C:\windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefd380000 - 0x000007fefd388000     C:\windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fef9760000 - 0x000007fef979b000     C:\windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000007fefb8e0000 - 0x000007fefb8ec000     C:\windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x0000000077350000 - 0x0000000077357000     C:\windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000001cf0000 - 0x0000000001cff000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x000000006cc80000 - 0x000000006cca9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\java.dll
0x000000006d3c0000 - 0x000000006d3f5000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\jdwp.dll
0x0000000063e20000 - 0x0000000063e28000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\npt.dll
0x0000000070410000 - 0x0000000070426000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefcfc0000 - 0x000007fefcfcf000     C:\windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x0000000063e10000 - 0x0000000063e19000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\dt_socket.dll
0x000007fefbfa0000 - 0x000007fefbff5000     C:\windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefb9b0000 - 0x000007fefb9b7000     C:\windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x0000000001e60000 - 0x0000000001e7a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefbf90000 - 0x000007fefbf97000     C:\windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007fefbe20000 - 0x000007fefbe7b000     C:\windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x00000000747d0000 - 0x00000000747f6000     C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll
0x000007fefa450000 - 0x000007fefa477000     C:\windows\system32\Iphlpapi.DLL
0x000007fefa440000 - 0x000007fefa44b000     C:\windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef87c0000 - 0x000007fef87c8000     C:\windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fef8cd0000 - 0x000007fef8d23000     C:\windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x000007fefc000000 - 0x000007fefc017000     C:\windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefbd00000 - 0x000007fefbd47000     C:\windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefcff0000 - 0x000007fefd00e000     C:\windows\system32\USERENV.dll
```

Comment: If it only occurs when running in parallel it might be some memory that is accessed by one thread in the DLL but has already been freed in another thread. You'd have to check the DLL for that.

Comment: The exception happens in `jPortfolioPrecision` dll, not in Java code. Probably this library is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
If yopu see the crash logs
Crash has occured in native code.
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jPortfolioPrecision-2.24.0.dll+0xe9fee]
#
Parallally you can check the stack trace of Java code. Which is leading to crash.
Problematic thread is ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2.
You need to correct your native code..

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.axiomainc.portfolioprecision2.Portfolio.release()V+0
j  com.axiomainc.portfolioprecision.optimization.RebalancingSolution$RebRunInfo.destroy()V+107
J 3775 C1 com.axiomainc.portfolioprecision.optimization.RebalancingSolution.resetRebRunInfo()V (20 bytes) @ 0x00000000032c0d5c [0x00000000032c0c80+0xdc]
j  com.axiomainc.portfolioprecision.optimization.RebalancingSolution.reset()V+65
J 4098 C1 Auction$$Lambda$1.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V (8 bytes) @ 0x0000000003d88ddc [0x0000000003d88b00+0x2dc]
J 4097 C1 java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V (11 bytes) @ 0x0000000002f5cc5c [0x0000000002f5cb40+0x11c]
j  java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)V+99
j  java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Ljava/util/stream/Sink;Ljava/util/Spliterator;)V+32
j  java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute()V+103
j  java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec()Z+1
j  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec()I+10
j  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Ljava/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask;)V+21
j  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue;)V+35``
j  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run()V+24
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```